# backtrader how to use analyzer to access data?

Tags: csv, analyzer, writer, backtrader

I am very new to this.
backtrader have a addwriter can write down some data,
 `cerebro.addwriter(bt.WriterFile, csv=True, out='outputfiles3\{}cerebro.csv'.format(ticker))`
but buy and sell price always not match to the execute price.

so alternatively:

i did `cerebro.addanalyzer(WritingAnalyzer)` before `cerebro.run()`

so I am trying to build the csv file with 'datetime','open','close','cash','value','position size'
but I don't know how to access those data. I can only point at current day close price with `self.data[0]`

I don't know how to do it right. I hope someone might able to give me some directions.

```
import backtrader as bt
from backtrader import Analyzer
import csv

class WritingAnalyzer(Analyzer):

    def __init__(self):

    def create_analysis(self):
        self.counter = 0
        print(self.counter)
        with open('demo1.csv',mode='w') as csv_file:
            fieldnames=['datetime','open','close','cash','value','position size']
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()

    def next(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print('close price:',self.data[0], "counter:",self.counter,)
        #  the following line suppose to write into csv file but i dont know how to get most of the data.
        bt.writer.writerow({'datetime': '??', 'open': '??', 'close': self.data[0],'cash':'??','value':'??','position size':'??'})

    def stop(self):
        print("SSSSSSSSSSSSSTTTTTTOOOOOOOOOOOOPPPPPPPPPP")

        self.rets._close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to handle your analyzer a bit differently. You can literally grab data at every bar and then have it available to you at the end.

Create a new analyzer, in my case I made:

```
class BarAnalysis(bt.analyzers.Analyzer):
```

In your analyzer in start you will create a new list.

```
def start(self):
    self.rets = list()
```

Then in next you will add a list of data for each bar. I use a try statement just in case there are any data problems, but it's probably not necessary. `Strategy` is included as as subclass and you can use its methods by calling `self.strategy.getvalue()` as an example.

```
def next(self):
    try:
        self.rets.append(
            [
                self.datas[0].datetime.datetime(),
                self.datas[0].open[0],
                self.datas[0].high[0],
                self.datas[0].low[0],
                self.datas[0].close[0],
                self.datas[0].volume[0],
                self.strategy.getposition().size,
                self.strategy.broker.getvalue(),
                self.strategy.broker.getcash(),
            ]
        )
    except:
        pass
```

Finally create a `get_analysis` method that you can use to get your results at the end.

```
def get_analysis(self):
    return self.rets
```

Add your analyzer to before running cerebro. You can name it whatever you want, we'll need the name to call the results.

```
cerebro.addanalyzer(BarAnalysis, _name="bar_data")
```

Make sure you provide a variable for the results of the cerebro.run() method so you can collect the results of the backtest.

```
strat = cerebro.run()
```

Finally, get the data out of strat and do as you wish with it. In this case I'm creating a dataframe and printing.

```
bar_data_res = strat[0].analyzers.bar_data.get_analysis()
df = pd.DataFrame(bar_data_res)
print(df)
```

And the printout looks like:

```
/home/runout/projects/rb_master/venv/bin/python /home/runout/projects/scratch/20210424_analyzer.py
                             0       1       2  ...  6         7         8
0   2020-01-02 23:59:59.999989  212.70  213.36  ...  0  10000.00  10000.00
1   2020-01-03 23:59:59.999989  210.81  213.28  ...  0  10000.00  10000.00
2   2020-01-06 23:59:59.999989  210.18  213.59  ...  0  10000.00  10000.00
3   2020-01-07 23:59:59.999989  213.11  214.13  ...  0  10000.00  10000.00
4   2020-01-08 23:59:59.999989  212.43  216.47  ...  0  10000.00  10000.00
..                         ...     ...     ...  ... ..       ...       ...
247 2020-12-23 23:59:59.999989  268.38  269.31  ...  1  10015.38   9747.25
248 2020-12-24 23:59:59.999989  267.76  269.67  ...  1  10016.48   9747.25
249 2020-12-28 23:59:59.999989  270.48  270.55  ...  1  10014.82   9747.25
250 2020-12-29 23:59:59.999989  268.30  268.78  ...  1  10011.78   9747.25
251 2020-12-30 23:59:59.999989  264.45  265.64  ...  1  10010.86   9747.25

[252 rows x 9 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
import datetime
import backtrader as bt
import pandas as pd

class BarAnalysis(bt.analyzers.Analyzer):

    def start(self):
        self.rets = list()

    def next(self):
        try:
            self.rets.append(
                [
                    self.datas[0].datetime.datetime(),
                    self.datas[0].open[0],
                    self.datas[0].high[0],
                    self.datas[0].low[0],
                    self.datas[0].close[0],
                    self.datas[0].volume[0],
                    self.strategy.getposition().size,
                    self.strategy.broker.getvalue(),
                    self.strategy.broker.getcash(),
                ]
            )
        except:
            pass

    def get_analysis(self):
        return self.rets


class Strategy(bt.Strategy):

    params = (
        ("lowerband", 30),
        ("upperband", 70),
    )

    def __init__(self):
        self.rsi = bt.ind.RSI(period=10)

    def next(self):
        if not self.position:
            if self.rsi <= self.p.lowerband:
                self.buy()
        elif self.rsi >= self.p.upperband:
            self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()

    ticker = "HD"
    data = bt.feeds.YahooFinanceData(
        dataname=ticker,
        timeframe=bt.TimeFrame.Days,
        fromdate=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
        todate=datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31),
        reverse=False,
    )

    cerebro.adddata(data, name=ticker)

    cerebro.addanalyzer(BarAnalysis, _name="bar_data")
    cerebro.addstrategy(Strategy)

    # Execute
    strat = cerebro.run()

    bar_data_res = strat[0].analyzers.bar_data.get_analysis()
    df = pd.DataFrame(bar_data_res)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time.  @run-out. you explained very well.  is there a way to pull a cost basis within the ```try: self.rets.append() ``` ?

Comment: Add this line to your analyzer: `                    self.strategy.getposition().adjbase,
`

Comment: Thank you. can you tell me how did you find this out? It is easy for me to search and verify after you post your answer. but I wasn't able to find it if you don't answer me.

Comment: getposition is used primiarly for size and price, but if you print it out you'll see there are a few more fields tracking data. Try in next: `print(self.getposition())` and you'll get something like: --- Position Begin
- Size: 1
- Price: 267.01
- Price orig: 0.0
- Closed: 0
- Opened: 1
- Adjbase: 264.53
--- Position End

Comment: `self.strategy.getposition().adjbase,` is the close price of the current day if holding positions. and when no position (0 positions) returns the close price of the last day that holding any position.  I am looking for 0 if nothing holding position, the (purchase price* number of positions) for the day holding the position(actural cost).  someone suggested self.broker.getcommissioninfo(data), but cannot pass 'data' in to class.